# Own symbol server for C++ Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to find a step-by-step instruction how to setup my own symbol server for Visual Studio but only end up finding how to setup the IDE. Can anyone point me to which symbol server I can install where I can upload my PDB files that can then be used across several machines? Thanks!